# Entering UK with Two different Visas?

Tags: visas, uk

Earlier this year I received a Business Visitor visa for the UK which is valid until 15 Nov, 2017. I went there for a business meeting that was successful and therefore I've received a Diplomatic Visa for the UK today. The start date for my diplomatic visa is 25 Sep, 2017. MY Employer made the same (25 Sep) my start day at work.

My Question is if I can enter the UK on my initial business visa on the 20th of Sep so I can sort out my accommodation etc before I begin work on the 26th at my office?

Thanks

Comment: 25th* and BTW; My Business visitor visa is multi-entry!

Comment: Good question, but probably better suited to [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: Yes, but only up until the start date of your work visa, after that your visitor visa is invalid and reportable as a change in circumstances. Whether or not you have to channel hop on 24 Sept is down to the discretion of the IO who lands you on 20 Sept

Comment: @GayotFow Should I post this over on Expatriates as suggested above? I wasn't expecting an answer here tbh after that comment.

Comment: Not necessary, leaving it here is fine because it's about your visitor visa. Next time however if it's about your work permit, use Expats, many thanks